# Loading pages on local machine fails due to disallowed MIME type (text/html)

Tags: iis, bootstrap-4, mime-types

I have simple web using bootstrap framework and some php parts. Everything is running on IIS ver. 10.
When I want to load site on my PC it fails loading .css and .js files. One of the errors is:

> Loading module from “http://127.0.0.1:1488/js/material.js” was blocked
> because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).

I've tried many things and the funny part is that same site is running properly on other PC (Windows 10, IIS 10). The folder structure and path are the same on both machines.

Is there any option is IIS to configure which I somehow missed?

Comment: The server thinks that your JS file is a HTML file, this may be because the server-side recognition is buggy or the JS file is non-existent or there is no js in it. Because of that, it sends the Content-Type text/html. The browser sees the content type, thinks this is no css and does not allow it. If you specify the type(client side) or change the type server-side, it should work.

Comment: @samwu where to change the type?